# JHipster front end failing to return certain sets of js bundles

Tags: angular, typescript, bundle, jhipster

I'm running a JHipster app, front end only. When running on a server (in a Kubernetes), the app fails to load one or the other of these two sets of .js bundles, depending on seemingly unrelated proxy settings:

Set 1:

- manifest.bundle.js
- main.bundle.js
- global.bundle.js

Set 2:

- vendor.bundle.js
- polyfill.bundle.js

This comes with other very odd behavior, like returning a 404 for the entire page after a hard cache reset.

Any clues to this very strange set of behaviors would be appreciated.

NOTE: 2020-08-12 - found that this seems to be related to a backend deployment that somehow prevents approximately 50% of requests from properly reaching the front end. In practice, it sometimes seems as if it is specific to certain .js bundles, but further experimentation indicates that it is almost random. If I make requests to retrieve individual .js bundles works almost exactly 50% of the time.
Wrote a new SO item: [Kubernetes deployment of two microservices at same subdomain resulting in frequent and random 404 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63379139/kubernetes-deployment-of-two-microservices-at-same-subdomain-resulting-in-freque)

Comment: Files are being served by default JHipster code, nothing special.

Comment: Could you explain how "frontend only" and "served by default JHipster code" could work? If it's frontend only then the java backend  has not been generated and cannot serve your frontend bundle.

Comment: The front-end is started via npm -start, which I believe to mean that it's a nodejs server.

Comment: I just read your other question and I think I understand your setup. You're not using the jhipster nodejs blueprint, you're using the main generator but separated the frontend from the java backend. Unfortunately, webpack dev server that you use when running `npm start` is not intended to be used in production, your bundle should be deployed to a web server like nginx.